# XUnit and F# core 4.3.1 loading errors when in Class Library

Tags: .net, nuget, xunit, assembly-binding-redirect

I have this very confusing issue with (probably) XUnit and a number of Nuget packages. My solution consists of a C# project that is not relevant to this problem and a F# tests project.

The tests project is a very simple Class Library project with one .fs file that contains all the tests and a few NuGet packages three of which are (IMO) important: `fsUnitxUnit` in version 1.4.1.0, `XUnit` in version 2.1.0, and `FSharp.Core` in version 4.0.0.1.

The problem is that the tests always fail on `Could not load file or assembly FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.1.0` when both following conditions are true: the NuGet referenced `FSharp.Core` is of version 4.0.0.[10] and the project's type is Class library.

When either the NuGet `FSharp.Core` is manually downgraded to version 3.1.2.5 or the projet's type is changed to Console Aplication then the exception doesn't get thrown and all tests pass as they should.

As if that wasn't weird enough it does this only on Windows. On Linux (or at least travis-cl (as shown [here](https://travis-ci.org/petrroll/TravisTest/builds))) everything works well in every configuration.

Linked [here](https://github.com/petrroll/TravisTest/commits/master) is testing repo. Last three commits show which configurations work and which don't. The last "does also work" configuration doesn't have appropriate travis config file but works both on Windows and Travis as well (tests pass).

Disclaimer: I'm absolutely new to NuGet packages so I might be missing something very basic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that FsUnit.xUnit references FSharp.Core 4.3.1.0 whilst your project is using a different version.

You should be able resolve this by using a [binding redirect](https://fsharp.github.io/2015/04/18/fsharp-core-notes.html#use-binding-redirects-for-applications).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    ...
    <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.1.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I believe you should be able to put this into your test project's app.config and xunit should find and use the generated .dll.config file. I would try that first. Otherwise you could put the binding redirect into xunit.console.exe.config so it is used when you run xunit.console.exe.

Comment: Ok, I get that but how come the problem arrises only when the project's type is Class Library?

Comment: Not sure. Are you building the .exe in Visual Studio 2013 or higher and targeting .NET 4.5.1? Visual Studio will automatically [add binding redirects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2(v=vs.110).aspx) for desktop/console apps if they are compiled against .NET 4.5.1

Comment: Yep, that is probably it. Thanks! :)